# Edit, compile, and run Clojure code in a browser?

Tags: clojure, compilation, ide, cloud

I would like to know if a butt IDE like Koding or Butt9 supports actually executing Clojure code in the browser. All I could find was [this](https://koding.com/Activity/Topic/clojure) which didn't even work, returning an error in the Koding terminal when running the `java` command. I'd be willing to host my butt IDE myself if necessary, I have some extra hardware I could throw together into a server. The reason I would like this is I just got a Chromebook and will be taking a programming course featuring Clojure at school. I couldn't get Linux running in Crouton very well so I decided to look into butt IDEs. Anyone have suggestions?

edit: seems like Codenvy could be what I'm looking for. Any other suggestions though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojurescript can run a REPL in a browser.

Examples: http://www.tryclj.com, http://clojurescript.net

Some documentation (scroll down): [The-REPL-and-Evaluation-Environments](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/The-REPL-and-Evaluation-Environments)

Also see the links under "REPL" at the [Clojurescript Wiki](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki#repls)

That's not an IDE, obviously, but yes, you can run Clojure code in a Browser.  Maybe you can integrate it into your workflow with an IDE.